# Converting pdf files into data.frames

Tags: r, pdf, tm

I'm currently trying to create a function that will read many pdf files into a data frame. My ultimate goal is to have it read specific information from the pdf files and convert them into a data.frame with insurance plan names in each row and the columns comprising of information I need such as individual plan price, family plan prices, etc. I have been following an [answer given by someone for a similar question in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244709/how-to-convert-data-from-pdf-files-into-data-frames). However, I keep getting an error. Here is a link to two different files I am practicing on([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNLgs.jpg) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2c9w.jpg)).

Here are my code and error below:

```
PDFtoDF = function(file) {

  dat = readPDF(control=list(text="-layout"))(elem=list(uri=file), 
                                              language="en", id="id1") 
  dat = c(as.character(dat))

  dat = gsub("^ ?([0-9]{1,3}) ?", "\\1|", dat)

  dat = gsub("(, HVOL )","\\1 ", dat)
  dat = gsub(" {2,100}", "|", dat)

  excludeRows = lapply(gregexpr("\\|", dat), function(x) length(x)) != 6
  write(dat[excludeRows], "rowsToCheck.txt", append=TRUE)

  dat = dat[!excludeRows]

  dat = read.table(text=dat, sep="", quote="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  names(dat) = c("Plan", "Individual", "Family")
  return(dat)
}

files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")

df = do.call("rbind", lapply(files, PDFtoDF))


    Error in read.table(text = dat, sep = "", quote = "", stringsAsFactors = 
    FALSE) : no lines available in input
```

Before this approach, I have been using the pdftools package and regular expressions. This approach worked except it was difficult to clarify a pattern for some parts of the document such as the plan name which is at the top. I was hoping the methodology I'm trying now will help since it will extract the text into separate strings for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best answer:

```
require(readtext)
df <- readtext("*.pdf")
```

Yes it's that simple, with the **readtext** package!

Comment: When I print the "text" variable it creates for the pdf's text, the variable shows some of it in the console and then says <truncated>. Does this mean that all of the information from the pdf is stored but is too long to print it out in the console?

This may work by the way--thanks! I think I can try figuring out how to split that one variable into multiple variable and then begin grabbing information I need from it and put them into their own cells/variables for each document. I assume it shouldn't be too difficult to learn how to make a function w/loop to do it to many pdfs.

Comment: It's just a data.frame, and the text column is called (in your example) `df$text`. However the **readtext** package borrows the print method from **tibble**, so that you can see a version of the object in the console. The truncation is just for printing, not anything that has been done to the object.

Comment: I appreciate the help! My ultimate goal is to be able to grab pricing data as well as specific wording/sentences from each pdf which will be put into a database. Do you have any advice on an optimal methodology for this project or packages that would be beneficial? I'm worried that purely using  basic regular expressions to find patterns, split them into the variable I want, and then convert into a column variable might not be the best approach lol