# R tabulizer: PDF Encoding Errors (?)

Tags: r, pdf, tabulizer

I'm trying to parse some historic crude oil price data using tabulizer and running into what appear to be encoding errors.  Below is a reproducible example with one of the files I want to scrape.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tabulizer)
library(pdftools)
#example file
file <- "https://paalp.s3.amazonaws.com/plains/media/bulletins/paa/monthly/2000/December%202000.pdf"

#download file
#check file info - nothing on encoding per se
pdf_info(file)
```

The pdf_info returns nothing extraordinary except that the file is relatively old. I've tried to run these as tables or as text and I get different types of errors, but the text call seems to reveal where the issues might be.

```
#attempt to parse table from page 1
pricing_tables<-extract_tables(file,page=1)

#grab as text
pricing_text<-extract_text("Files/test.pdf",page=1)
```

When I grab as a table,the first columns of pricing are not deliminted, extra decimals are inserted, etc.

[image: Data frame view]

When I grad as text, I can see the encoding characters which seem to throw some of it for a loop.

```
West Texas Intermediate - Area #1...................................................â€¦......................................................â€¦30.75 * 28 75 * 28 00 * 26.25 * 26.75 * 26.25 *\r\n
```

A couple of other testing bits.  First, I can render the PDF into a bitmap and the content transfers appropritely. Not sure whether that is informative at all.

```
# render into raw bitmap
bitmap <- pdf_render_page(file)
png::writePNG(bitmap, "test.png")
```

Next, the same errors are reproduced if I copy from the PDF into Excel:

[image: Excel test]

And the same thing in Word:
[image: Word test]

Any thoughts or help much appreciated.

Andrew

Comment: Greg made an attempt here with Python.  Improves a bit but still hangs on the same characters https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1n0cz7VHUyQon2amUpazlYljpx37-_PQc

Comment: @eipi10 I found your solution to a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244709/how-to-convert-data-from-pdf-files-into-data-frames and I am working to implement it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to extract the tables with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(magick)

path_PDF <- "C:\\December%202000.pdf"
path_Word <- "C:\\temp.docx"

####################################################################
#### Step 1 : We use the OCR of Word to convert the PDF to word ####
####################################################################
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_PDF),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

doc$SaveAs2(path_Word)

###############################################
#### Step 2 : Convert word document to pdf ####
###############################################
nb_Table <- doc$tables()$count()
list_Table <- list()

for(l in 1 : nb_Table)
{
  nb_Row <- doc$tables(l)$Rows()$Count()
  nb_Col <- doc$tables(l)$Columns()$Count()
  mat_Temp <- matrix(NA, nrow = nb_Row, ncol = nb_Col)
  
  for(i in 1 : nb_Row)
  {
    for(j in 1 : nb_Col)
    {
      mat_Temp[i, j] <- tryCatch(doc$tables(l)$cell(i, j)$range()$text(), error = function(e) NA)
    }
  }
  
  list_Table[[l]] <- mat_Temp
}

list_Table

[[1]]
      [,1]                                                                                                                                                         
 [1,] "\tBULLETIN NO:\t2000-199\r\a"                                                                                                                                 
 [2,] "\tEFFECTIVE DATE:\t    11-30-00\r\a"                                                                                                                          
 [3,] "     $/BBL\rTEXAS\r\a"                                                                                                                                      
 [4,] "  West Texas Intermediate - Area #1..............................\t30.75 *\r\a"                                                                              
 [5,] "  West Texas Intermediate - All Other Areas..................\t31.00 *\r\a"                                                                                  
 [6,] "  West Texas Sour.........................................................\t28.00 *\r\a"                                                                     
 [7,] "  West Central Texas......................................................\t31.00 *\r\a"                                                                     
 [8,] "  North Texas Sweet.......................................................\t31.00 *\r\a"                                                                     
 [9,] "  North Texas (Cooke & Grayson) Sweet........................\t31.00 *\r\a"                                                                                  
[10,] "  North Texas (Cooke & Grayson) Sour..........................\t29.90 *\r\a"                                                                                 
[11,] "  East Texas Field..........................................................\t30.75 *\r\a"                                                                   
[12,] "  East Texas (Other than E. TX. Field)............................\t30.75 *\r\a"                                                                             
[13,] "  East Texas Sour...........................................................\t24.50 *\r\a"                                                                   
[14,] "  East Texas Light Sour..................................................\t28.75 *\r\a"                                                                      
[15,] "  Texas Upper Gulf Coast...............................................\t30.00 *\r\a"                                                                        
[16,] "  Texas Central Gulf Coast (Giddings).............................\t30.00 *\r\a"                                                                             
[17,] "  South Texas Light (Sweet)............................................\t30.00 *\r\a"                                                                        
[18,] "  Big Wells Intermediate..................................................\t29.75 *\r\a"                                                                     
[19,] "  South Texas Heavy.......................................................\t30.00 *\r\a"                                                                     
[20,] "  South Texas Sour.........................................................\t27.25 *\r\a"                                                                    
[21,] "NEW MEXICO\t \r\a"                                                                                                                                           
[22,] "  New Mexico Intermediate..............................................\t31.00 *\r\a"                                                                        
[23,] "  New Mexico Sour.........................................................\t28.00 *\r\a"                                                                     
[24,] "LOUISIANA\t \r\a"                                                                                                                                            
[25,] "  North Louisiana............................................................\t30.75 *\r\a"                                                                  
[26,] "  Central Louisiana Sweet.........................................................................\r\a"                                                     
[27,] "  South Louisiana Light Sweet (Onshore)........................\t30.75 *\r\a"                                                                                
[28,] "  Ferriday Area....................................\r\a"                                                                                                    
[29,] "  South Louisiana Eugene Island (Onshore)....................\r\a"                                                                                          
[30,] "COLORADO\t \r\a"                                                                                                                                             
[31,] "  Colorado Southeastern.................................................\r\a"                                                                               
[32,] "  Colorado Eastern..........................................................\r\a"                                                                           
[33,] "  Colorado Denver Area...................................................\r\a"                                                                              
[34,] "  Colorado Western.........................................................\r\a"                                                                            
[35,] "ILLINOIS\t \r\a"                                                                                                                                             
[36,] "  Illinois Sweet.................................................................\r\a"                                                                      
[37,] "INDIANA\t \r\a"                                                                                                                                              
[38,] "  Indiana Sweet...............................................................\r\a"                                                                         
[39,] "KANSAS\t \r\a"                                                                                                                                               
[40,] "  Kansas Common..........................................................\r\a"                                                                              
[41,] "  Eastern Kansas Common.............................................\r\a"                                                                                   
[42,] "  Northwest Kansas Sweet..............................................\r\a"                                                                                 
[43,] "  Southwest Kansas Sweet.............................................\r\a"                                                                                  
[44,] "KENTUCKY\t \r\a"                                                                                                                                             
[45,] "  Western Kentucky Sweet.............................................\r\a"                                                                                  
[46,] "MISSISSIPPI\r\a"                                                                                                                                            
[47,] "  Mississippi Light Sweet & Sour.....................................\r\a"                                                                                  
[48,] "NEBRASKA\t \r\a"                                                                                                                                             
[49,] "  Nebraska Western........................................................\r\a"                                                                             
[50,] "NORTH DAKOTA\r\a"                                                                                                                                           
[51,] "  Williston Basin Sweet...................................................\r\a"                                                                             
[52,] "  Williston Basin Sour......................................................\r\a"                                                                           
[53,] "OKLAHOMA\t \r\a"                                                                                                                                             
[54,] "  Domestic Sweet (Cushing)..........................…\r\a"                                                                                                  
[55,] "  Oklahoma Sweet..........................................................\r\a"                                                                             
[56,] "  Oklahoma Sweet-Central..............................................\r\a"                                                                                 
[57,] "  Western Oklahoma (effective Nov. 14, 2000)..................\r\a"                                                                                         
[58,] "  Oklahoma Panhandle (effective Nov. 14, 2000) ............\r\a"                                                                                            
[59,] "WYOMING\r\a"                                                                                                                                                
[60,] "  Wyoming Southwestern Area.......................................\r\a"                                                                                     
[61,] "  Wyoming Southeastern Area........................................\r\a"                                                                                    
[62,] "  Wyoming Sweet Other Areas.......................................\r\a"                                                                                     
[63,] "  Wyoming General Sour................................................\r\a"                                                                                 
[64,] "  Wyoming Asphaltic Sour.............................................. 27.00 *  1 The gravity adjustment scale and other terms are set forth on Page 5.\r\a"
      [,2]               [,3]               [,4]               [,5]              
 [1,] "2000-200\r\a"     "2000-201\r\a"     "2000-202\r\a"     "2000-203\r\a"    
 [2,] "    12-01-00\r\a" "    12-04-00\r\a" "    12-05-00\r\a" "    12-06-00\r\a"
 [3,] "     $/BBL\r\a"   "     $/BBL\r\a"   "     $/BBL\r\a"   "     $/BBL\r\a"  
 [4,] "\r\a"             "28.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"     
 [5,] "\r\a"             "29.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.25 *\r\a"     
 [6,] "\r\a"             "26.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "25.25 *\r\a"     
 [7,] "\r\a"             "29.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.25 *\r\a"     
 [8,] "\r\a"             "29.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.25 *\r\a"     
 [9,] "\r\a"             "29.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.25 *\r\a"     
[10,] "\r\a"             "27.90 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "27.15 *\r\a"     
[11,] "\r\a"             "28.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"     
[12,] "\r\a"             "28.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"     
[13,] "\r\a"             "22.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "21.75 *\r\a"     
[14,] "\r\a"             "26.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "26.00 *\r\a"     
[15,] "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "27.00 *\r\a"     
[16,] "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "27.00 *\r\a"     
[17,] "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "27.25 *\r\a"     
[18,] "\r\a"             "27.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "27.00 *\r\a"     
[19,] "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "27.25 *\r\a"     
[20,] "\r\a"             "25.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "24.50 *\r\a"     
[21,] " \r\a"            "\r\a"             " \r\a"            "\r\a"            
[22,] "\r\a"             "29.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.25 *\r\a"     
[23,] "\r\a"             "26.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "25.25 *\r\a"     
[24,] " \r\a"            "\r\a"             " \r\a"            "\r\a"            
[25,] "28.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[26,] "28.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[27,] "28.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "27.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[28,] "31.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "29.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[29,] "28.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "26.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[30,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"            "\r\a"             " \r\a"           
[31,] "29.85 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "27.85 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[32,] "29.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "27.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[33,] "30.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[34,] "33.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "31.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[35,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"            "\r\a"             " \r\a"           
[36,] "31.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "29.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[37,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"            "\r\a"             " \r\a"           
[38,] "31.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "29.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[39,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"            "\r\a"             " \r\a"           
[40,] "30.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[41,] "30.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[42,] "30.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[43,] "30.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[44,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"            "\r\a"             " \r\a"           
[45,] "31.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "29.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[46,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"            "\r\a"             " \r\a"           
[47,] "30.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[48,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"            "\r\a"             " \r\a"           
[49,] "29.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "27.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[50,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"            "\r\a"             " \r\a"           
[51,] "29.30 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "27.30 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[52,] "26.65 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "24.65 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[53,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"            "\r\a"             " \r\a"           
[54,] "31.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "29.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[55,] "31.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "29.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[56,] "31.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "29.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[57,] "30.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[58,] "30.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[59,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"            "\r\a"             " \r\a"           
[60,] "31.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "29.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[61,] "30.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[62,] "30.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "28.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[63,] "27.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "25.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"            
[64,] "\r\a"             "25.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"             "24.25 *\r\a"     
      [,6]               [,7]          [,8]          [,9]          [,10]         [,11]        
 [1,] "2000-204\r\a"     NA            NA            NA            NA            NA           
 [2,] "    12-07-00\r\a" NA            NA            NA            NA            NA           
 [3,] "     $/BBL\r\a"   NA            NA            NA            NA            NA           
 [4,] "\r\a"             "26.25 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.25 *\r\a"
 [5,] "\r\a"             "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a"
 [6,] "\r\a"             "23.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "24.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "23.50 *\r\a"
 [7,] "\r\a"             "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a"
 [8,] "\r\a"             "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a"
 [9,] "\r\a"             "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a"
[10,] "\r\a"             "25.40 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.90 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.40 *\r\a"
[11,] "\r\a"             "26.25 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.25 *\r\a"
[12,] "\r\a"             "26.25 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.25 *\r\a"
[13,] "\r\a"             "20.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "20.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "20.00 *\r\a"
[14,] "\r\a"             "24.25 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "24.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "24.25 *\r\a"
[15,] "\r\a"             "25.25 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.25 *\r\a"
[16,] "\r\a"             "25.25 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.25 *\r\a"
[17,] "\r\a"             "25.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.50 *\r\a"
[18,] "\r\a"             "25.25 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.25 *\r\a"
[19,] "\r\a"             "25.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.50 *\r\a"
[20,] "\r\a"             "22.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "23.25 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "22.75 *\r\a"
[21,] " \r\a"            "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"       
[22,] "\r\a"             "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a"
[23,] "\r\a"             "23.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "24.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "23.50 *\r\a"
[24,] " \r\a"            "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"       
[25,] "26.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.25 *\r\a" NA           
[26,] "26.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.25 *\r\a" NA           
[27,] "26.00 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.00 *\r\a" NA           
[28,] "28.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "27.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[29,] "25.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "23.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "24.25 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[30,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"      
[31,] "27.10 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "25.35 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.85 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[32,] "26.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "25.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[33,] "27.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "25.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[34,] "30.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "29.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "29.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[35,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"      
[36,] "28.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[37,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"      
[38,] "28.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[39,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"      
[40,] "27.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "25.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.25 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[41,] "27.50 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "25.75 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.25 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[42,] "27.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "25.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[43,] "27.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "25.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[44,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"      
[45,] "28.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[46,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"      
[47,] "27.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[48,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"      
[49,] "26.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "25.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[50,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"      
[51,] "26.55 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "24.80 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "25.30 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[52,] "23.90 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "22.15 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "22.65 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[53,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"       "\r\a"        " \r\a"      
[54,] "28.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"       
[55,] "28.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.00\r\a"   "\r\a"       
[56,] "28.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.00\r\a"   "\r\a"       
[57,] "27.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.50\r\a"   "\r\a"       
[58,] "27.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.50\r\a"   "\r\a"       
[59,] "\r\a"             " \r\a"       "\r\a"        "\r\a"        "\r\a"        " \r\a"      
[60,] "28.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "27.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "27.50\r\a"   "\r\a"       
[61,] "27.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "25.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.00\r\a"   "\r\a"       
[62,] "27.75 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "26.00 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "26.50\r\a"   "\r\a"       
[63,] "24.25 *\r\a"      "\r\a"        "22.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "23.00\r\a"   "\r\a"       
[64,] "\r\a"             "22.50 *\r\a" "\r\a"        "23.00\r\a"   "\r\a"        "22.50\r\a"  
      [,12]        
 [1,] NA           
 [2,] NA           
 [3,] NA           
 [4,] NA           
 [5,] NA           
 [6,] NA           
 [7,] NA           
 [8,] NA           
 [9,] NA           
[10,] NA           
[11,] NA           
[12,] NA           
[13,] NA           
[14,] NA           
[15,] NA           
[16,] NA           
[17,] NA           
[18,] NA           
[19,] NA           
[20,] NA           
[21,] NA           
[22,] NA           
[23,] NA           
[24,] NA           
[25,] NA           
[26,] NA           
[27,] NA           
[28,] "27.00 *\r\a"
[29,] "23.75 *\r\a"
[30,] "\r\a"       
[31,] "25.35 *\r\a"
[32,] "25.00 *\r\a"
[33,] "25.50 *\r\a"
[34,] "29.00 *\r\a"
[35,] "\r\a"       
[36,] "26.50 *\r\a"
[37,] "\r\a"       
[38,] "26.50 *\r\a"
[39,] "\r\a"       
[40,] "25.75 *\r\a"
[41,] "25.75 *\r\a"
[42,] "25.50 *\r\a"
[43,] "25.50 *\r\a"
[44,] "\r\a"       
[45,] "26.50 *\r\a"
[46,] "\r\a"       
[47,] "26.00 *\r\a"
[48,] "\r\a"       
[49,] "25.00 *\r\a"
[50,] "\r\a"       
[51,] "24.80 *\r\a"
[52,] "22.15 *\r\a"
[53,] "\r\a"       
[54,] "26.50 *\r\a"
[55,] "26.50\r\a"  
[56,] "26.50\r\a"  
[57,] "26.00\r\a"  
[58,] "26.00\r\a"  
[59,] "\r\a"       
[60,] "27.00\r\a"  
[61,] "25.50\r\a"  
[62,] "26.00\r\a"  
[63,] "22.50\r\a"  
[64,] NA
```